# How can I calculate center coordinates for an infinite series of tangent hexagons?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, polygons

I'm trying to draw an infinite field of tangent hexagons, and am having trouble determining the centers in the series, as you can see from my [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngmar.png)

Not sure how to format my formulas since it's code, I'll do my best:

```
    oddColumn = (column % 2) - 1
    offsetY = oddColumn * radius

    centerX = diameter * column
    centerY = diameter * row + offsetY
```

So as you can see, I'm currently offsetting the Y position by the radius for oddColumns, but that leads to the hexagons being horizontally detached.

I need to calculate the corresponding 'offsetX' for odd columns (which should be negative to draw the rectangles closer to the previous columns) but don't know a formula for this.

Comment: Your attempt to do it should be diagonally, make the straight organization along an edge, not a vertex...

Comment: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the change that you want is best accomplished by making the horizontal positions $\frac{\sqrt 3}2$ diameters apart. The code might be ...

```
centerX = diameter * column * 0.5 * sqrt(3)
```

They should fit nicely once you do that.

**** EDIT

Label the vertices of a regular hexagon A through F starting at the top and proceeding clockwise.

The vertical height of the hexagon will be the distance between diametrically opposite points A and D.

The horizontal width of the hexagon will be the distance between the non diametrically opposite points F and B.

Consider the triangle FAB, since this is a regular hexagon...
$$|FA=|AB| = r $$
and these two sides meet at an angle of 120 degrees.

Applying cosine Law ...
$$ |FB|^2=r^2+r^2-2(r)(r)\cos(120)=3r^2  $$

So the width $|FB| = \sqrt 3 r = \frac {\sqrt 3}2 d$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please also provide your reasoning behind this solution?

Comment: @RedKnight91 I have edited my answer, I hope that is what you wanted to see.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot